# DataView Search on TextBox Change Event When DataSet is Local/Global

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, dataset, dataview

I have a DataGridView thats populated from Excel and a TextBox that acts as a search for that DataGridView using DataView on the DataSet after the TextBox text changed event.

My problem is that if i use a local DataSet in my Sub that populates the DataGridView then i can't access that DataSet on the TextBox change event.
On the other hand if i use the DataSet as a global variable , the performance for populating the DataGridView becomes awful (three times more than when using a local DataSet).

Wondering if there's any easy solution for this issue or maybe i should just settle for the slower loading time.

Thanks!

Code for populating DataGridView:

```
    Public Sub GetSKUTable(year As String)

    Dim q1, ColName, skuPath As String
    Dim Del As New List(Of String)
    Dim cn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    skuPath = GetSkuDefPath()
    'Get user local temp folder.
    Dim tempPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()

    'If temp directory doesn't exists - create it.
    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(tempPath) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath)
    End If

    Dim RndInt As Integer = GetRandomInt()
    Dim TempSKUpath As String = tempPath + "\tempSKUdef" + RndInt.ToString + ".xlsm"
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(skuPath, TempSKUpath)


    If skuPath.Contains("NULL") Or skuPath.Contains("NULLSTART") Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "data source=" + TempSKUpath + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;""")
    'Note: if the number of SKUs exceeds 295 - increase the selection range
    q1 = "select * from [" + year + "$B4:AM300]"
    da = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(q1, cn)

    'Open connection to SKU definitions Excel.
    Try
        cn.Open()
        da.Fill(ds, "Table1")
    Catch e As OleDb.OleDbException
        Dim errorMsg As String
        Dim i As Integer
        errorMsg = ""
        For i = 0 To e.Errors.Count - 1
            errorMsg += "Index #" & i.ToString() & ControlChars.Cr _
                           & "Message: " & e.Errors(i).Message & ControlChars.Cr _
                           & "NativeError: " & e.Errors(i).NativeError & ControlChars.Cr _
                           & "Source: " & e.Errors(i).Source & ControlChars.Cr _
                           & "SQLState: " & e.Errors(i).SQLState & ControlChars.Cr
        Next i
    End Try

    cn.Close()
    dt = ds.Tables(0)
    'Delete all columns that do not appear on the If condition.
    For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
       *** DELETED ***
        End If
    Next

    For Each ColName In Del
        dt.Columns.Remove(ColName)
    Next

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    'Delete temp SKU file.
    System.IO.File.Delete(TempSKUpath)
    'Delete temp folder if empty.
    Dim TempFileList As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
    TempFileList = My.Computer.FileSystem.FindInFiles(tempPath, "", True, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly)
    If TempFileList.Count() = 0 Then
        System.IO.Directory.Delete(tempPath)
    End If

End Sub
```

Code for search:

```
    Private Sub SKUdefSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SKUdefSearch.TextChanged

    'This method activates user open requests table search.
    Dim dvReq As DataView
    Dim SearchText, SearchString As String

    SearchText = SKUdefSearch.Text
    Select Case PYear.Text
        Case "2013", "2015"
            SearchString = DELETED
        Case "2014"
            SearchString = DELETED
        Case Else
            SearchString = "NULL"
    End Select

    If SearchString <> "NULL" Then
        If SearchText = "" Then
            dvReq = New DataView(ds.Tables(0), "", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dvReq
        Else
            dvReq = New DataView(ds.Tables(0), SearchString, "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dvReq
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Declaring a DataSet variable as global or Local should make no difference in the time required to populate it. It will be useful to see the code used.

Comment: Added the code , had to delete a few lines as this is for work and i don't think i'm allowed to post that data online :)
But those are only a few string that shouldn't have anything to do with performance.

Comment: Is it possible this might be an issue of where exactly i use ds.Clear() ?

Comment: Can't see any potential problem. Only the loops to remove columns could be unified to avoid two loops but this should not make a difference.